# Firing method on interval with System.Threading.Timer in winForm C#

Tags: c#, methods, timer, intervals

What I want to do is to use the System.Threading.Timer to execute a method with a interval.
My example  code looks like this atm.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Threading.Timer t1 = new System.Threading.Timer(WriteSomething, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
    }

    public void WriteSomething(object o)
    {

        textBox1.Text = "Test";
    }
}
```

}

Isn't this suppost to execute the WriteSomething method every 10'th second. What rly happens is that the WriteSomething is executed when I run my application and after 10 seconds the application closes. Think I have missunderstood how this works, can anyone tell me how to do this with the System.Threading.Timer.

thanks in advance, code examples are very welcome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an method execute on interval in windows form C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604227/making-an-method-execute-on-interval-in-windows-form-c)

Comment: Why do you want to use a Threading.Timer instead of a Forms.Timer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more likely scenario is that it *crashes* after 10 seconds.  You cannot touch any controls in the callback, it runs on the wrong thread.  You'd have to use Control.BeginInvoke().  Which makes it *utterly pointless* to use a System.Threading.Timer instead of a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

Be practical.  Make it 100 milliseconds so you don't grow a beard waiting for the crash.  And *don't* use an asynchronous timer to update the UI, it is useless.

Comment: nah not interested in using the drag and drop timer. Want to code it instead.

Comment: I can't, it is the wrong code.  Step-by-step: drop a Timer from the toolbox onto the form.  Double-click it.

Comment: Okay, open the Designer.cs file and cut-and-paste the code that was generated by the designer.

Comment: Code for using System.Windows.Forms.Timer is just...see answer below...easier to put code in an Answer.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, there is nothing about System.Windows.Forms timer that doesn't allow you to create in code (it's not just a "drag-and-drop" timer). Code:

Constructor code:

```
  System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
  timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
  timer.Interval = 10000;
  timer.Start();
```

Event Handler:

```
  private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Modify GUI here.
  }
```

Comment: +1 for following up, -1/4 for not preventing beard growth.  Net 1.

Answer (score 2):

Just to reiterate what Hans said, in a WinForms application all GUI elements are not inherently thread-safe. Almost all methods / properties on Control classes can only be called on the thread the GUI was created on. The System.Threading.Timer invokes its callback on a thread pool thread, not the the thread you created the timer on (see reference below from MSDN). As Hans said, you probably want a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead, that will invoke your callback on the correct thread.

You can always verify whether you can call methods on a Control (assuring you're on the correct thread) by using the code:

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(!InvokeRequired);

inside your event handler. If the assert trips, you're on a thread that cannot modify this Control.

Quote from MSDN help on [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.THREADING.TIMER%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) on the callback method you passed in the constructor:

> The method does not execute on the
>   thread that created the timer; it
>   executes on a ThreadPool thread
>   supplied by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Common error: need to keep timer variable as class member as garbage collector may kill it.